# Extension conversion ENVI .hdr to .icb

Tags: image-processing, compression, envi

Am working on Qccpack for Hyperspectral image compression which uses .icb extension.

How can I convert from ENVI .hdr to .icb in order to work with Qccpack ?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. please read [ask]. if you cannot find a converter via websearch, chances are very high that there is none. then you have to write your own converter. use the file specifications to do so. if you have problems on your way doing so you can ask for help here. but you should not expect that someone writes a 20 page tutorial if you only write 2 lines that don't contain much useful information

Answer (score 1):

I just had a quick look into the Qccpack documentation. (the first thing I found via google, I guess this is what you are talking about)

http://qccpack.sourceforge.net/Documentation/QccIMGImageCubeFree.3.html

.icb is a file that stores "image cubes". They say that image cubes are a data structure for saving volumetric image data.

ENVI .hdr instead is a file format that stores meta data for an image that is stored in another file.

**You cannot convert image meta data into image data.**